# a simple line concatenation problem using sed

Tags: sed

I have a large file containing data set names and dates/time:

```
ss:Type="String">EDII.HA5274.FNS99R.R999999.LFN5913.G1795V00</Data>
ss:Type="DateTime">2022-12-28T00:00:00.000</Data>
ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T23:50:14.000</Data>
ss:Type="String">EDII.HA5273.FNS9901R.R999999.LFN5913.G1796V00</Data>
ss:Type="DateTime">2022-12-29T00:00:00.000</Data>also,
ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T23:43:35.000</Data>
```

I want to concatenate the line following the word, "String".

My end result would be :

```
ss:Type="String">EDII.HA5274.FNS99R.R999999.LFN5913.G1795V00</Data>ss:Type="DateTime">2022-12- 28T00:00:00.000</Data>
ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T23:50:14.000</Data>
ss:Type="String">EDII.HA5273.FNS9901R.R999999.LFN5913.G1796V00</Data>ss:Type="DateTime">2022- -29T00:00:00.000</Data>
ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T23:43:35.000</Data>
```

My solution:

```
cat The_File.txt| sed 's/\(^.*String.*$\)\r\n/\1/g'
```

does nothing. "\r\n" are the correct eol characters. I can see them in my text editor.

I'm stuck now..

Any suggestions would be helpful. Also... what is wrong with my solution?

Thanks

Comment: You're working with some broken (or possibly purposely mangled) XML. It would be interesting to see what the original XML looked like and to know what you want to get out in the end (e.g. "get the `DateTime` value corresponding to some `String` value", or the other way around). That would allow us to suggest how to perform the task using some proper XML-aware tool.

Comment: I started with 200, 30000 line xml files.. My preprocess quick reduced this to one file with 9000 lines. Now I want to concatenate selected lines. I'm only inyerersted in using sed, ( or awk ).  This works: sed '/"String"/{N;s/\r\n//;}' . But only on a unix machine, or when I run it from cygwin. It doesn't work in MacOs.

Comment: Also, I don't have any xml aware tools, just Bash

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). If the line contains "String" print it without a newline, otherwise with one.

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = "\""; RS = "\r\n"}
    {printf "%s%s", $0, $2 == "String" ? "" : RS}
' The_File.txt
```

Comment: almost works. run as is, I got an "awk illegal statement at source line3". When I replaced "==" with "=" it worked.. sort of. it concatenated all lines after "String" I only wanted the first line following "String" to be concatenated.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is equality. With `$2 = "String"` the test becomes "is this an empty string", and it is not.

Answer (score 2):

By default, sed loads and processes a single line at a time.

To make it load a second line, you can use the `N` instruction. Then you can substitute the line ending character(s) with an empty string (or other joining string of your choice).

So

```
sed '/"String"/{N;s/\r\n//;}' TheFile.txt
```

Comment: This works great when I run it in cygwin on my windows machine,  but does nothing when I run it in a bash shell, on MacOs. I also tried it using gsed. I thought it might have been the eol characters, so I substituted eol with a letter from one of the lines. Still nothing..  It's really irritating when MacOs has issues with simple bash commands

Comment: hmmm did you mean "String" or String? my input file literally used the word "String". In any case my solution was to use    gsed  '/String/{N;s/\r\n//}',    and to drop the ending ";".  This works in MacOs. It may also work in Cygwin.. but I haven't tried it yet

Comment: Ignore my (rolled back) edits. I misread your command.

Answer (score -1):

This works in MacOs:

```
gsed '/String/{N;s/\r\n//}'
```

This works in Cygwin bash on a windows machine, and also on linux machine:

```
sed '/"String"/{N;s/\r\n//;}'
```

Comment: This seems to be duplicating [an earlier answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732531/116858). It would be best if you accepted that answer instead.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: No, you are incorrect.  In my case I have three environments, Windows with a cygwin shell, a Redhat Linux virtual machine, running on a Mac, and a Mac machine. The sed command works  in the  Linux environment, and the Windows/Cygwin/Bash shell. It does NOT work in in the OSX/Bash environment. The gsed command works in OSX. The sed command does not.  Its subtleties like this, that make, our jobs interesting

Comment: The substitution command in the `gsed` command is not terminated by a `;` before the `}`, which is a non-standard way to write sed expressions only understood by GNU `sed`.  Adding the missing `;` to the command makes it work in both GNU `sed` and in more standard compliant `sed` implementations, like those found on macOS and other BSD systems.  It is therefore slightly misleading to say that it depends on the operating system as GNU `sed` may well be installed as `sed` on macOS.  Correcting the `sed` expression so that it is standard compliant will make it work in any `sed` implementation.